# Generating new dataframe based on combination of rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that is indexed by `Race_ID`

```
Race_ID        Student_ID      Rank  
1              1               3     
1              2               2     
1              3               1     
1              4               4     
2              1               2     
2              2               3     
2              3               1
```

And I want to create a new dataframe based on the above dataframe by generating a new row using combination of each `Student_ID` within each `Race_ID`
So the outcome looks like

```
Race_ID   Student_ID_pair   Rank_sum
1         1-2               5
1         1-3               4        
1         1-4               7
1         2-3               3
1         2-4               6
1         3-4               5
2         1-2               5
2         1-3               3
2         2-3               4
```

So there are now 4C2=6 rows for `Race_ID = 1` and 3C2=3 rows for `Race_ID = 2`, and `Rank_sum` is just the sum of ranks of the respective students. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with a custom function and help from [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations

df['Student_ID'] = df['Student_ID'].astype(str)

def combine(g):
    a, b = map(list, zip(*combinations(g.index, r=2)))
    return pd.DataFrame(
        {'Race_ID': g.loc[a, 'Race_ID'],
         'Student_ID_pair': g.loc[a, 'Student_ID'] +'-'+ g.loc[b, 'Student_ID'].values,
         'Rank_sum': g.loc[a, 'Rank'] + g.loc[b, 'Rank'].values,
         })

out = (df.groupby('Race_ID', group_keys=False)
         .apply(combine).reset_index(drop=True)
      )
```

Alternative:

```
from itertools import combinations, chain

a, b = map(list, zip(*chain.from_iterable(df.groupby('Race_ID').apply(
             lambda g: list(combinations(g.index, r=2))
           ))))

out = pd.DataFrame(
        {'Race_ID': df.loc[a, 'Race_ID'],
         'Student_ID_pair': df.loc[a, 'Student_ID'] +'-'+ df.loc[b, 'Student_ID'].values,
         'Rank_sum': df.loc[a, 'Rank'] + df.loc[b, 'Rank'].values,
         })

print(out)
```

Output:

```
   Race_ID Student_ID_pair  Rank_sum
0        1             1-2         5
1        1             1-3         4
2        1             1-4         7
3        1             2-3         3
4        1             2-4         6
5        1             3-4         5
6        2             1-2         5
7        2             1-3         3
8        2             2-3         4
```